# An error when dynamically allocating memory for a char*

Tags: c++, arrays, char

So the main problem is there is run time error in the code:

```
char *wordBank[]= {new char[numWords+1]};
char  buffer1[41];

for(int i=0; i<numWords;i++){
    ifile >> buffer1;
    int len = strlen(buffer1);
    cout << buffer1<<"and"<<len <<endl;
    wordBank[i] = new char[len + 1];
    strncpy(wordBank[i], buffer1,len);
    cout << wordBank[i]<<"and"<<len <<endl;
}
```

is it starts to mess up with what is in wordBank. It gets the words from a txt file into buffer1 and then copy if into the dynamically allocated char* array of wordBank. However I always get segmentation fault and the words are all incorrect. What did I do wrong?

Comment: `wordbank` only has one element. `numWords` is the number of characters in that element.

Comment: You want: `std::string wordBank[MAX_WORDS];`. Don't mess with C-style strings.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews You want `std::vector<std::string> wordBank;` Don't mess with C!

Comment: @NeilKirk This is also C++.

Comment: Yes, a vector of strings is preferred.  I was performing conversion of only C-Style strings to `std::string`.

Comment: @NeilKirk I simply wanted to say that `char*`, pointers and all that stuff are also part of C++ and not just C, nothing else.

Comment: @Rinzler It was a joke :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line is wrong:

```
char *wordBank[] = {new char[numWords+1]};
```

`wordBank` is an array with one element, the value of that one element is a pointer to a character array with `numWords+1` characters. When you access `wordBank[1]` you're outside the bounds of the array, which results in undefined behavior.

What you apparently want is:

```
char **wordBank = new char*[numWords];
```

This creates a dynamically-allocated array of `numWords` `char*` elements, which you will then assign in the `for` loop.

I don't see any need for `numWords+1`.

Answer (score 3):

You can simplify the code using C++ instead of C:

```
vector<string> wordBank(numWords);
string buffer1;
for (int i = 0; i < numWords; i++) {
  ifile >> buffer1;
  size_t len = buffer1.length();
  cout << buffer1 << "and" << len << endl;
  wordBank[i] = buffer1;
  cout << wordBank[i] << "and" << len << endl;
}
```

Or even simpler, but adding error checking:

```
vector<string> wordBank(numWords);
for (int i = 0; i < numWords; i++) {
  if (ifile >> wordBank[i])
    cout << wordBank[i] << "and" << len << endl;
  else { // no more words
    wordBank.resize(i); // chop off the unused portion
    break;
  }
}
```